# Can I get emergency travel documents if I didn't lose my passport but don't have it in my possession?

Tags: dual-nationality, lost-documents, consulates

Let's say I travel abroad to country Z using passport A and leave or forget passport (UK) at home, and whilst abroad I lose passport A. Let's assume both A and UK can travel visa free to Z.

If for any reason I am unable or unwilling to get an emergency travel document from  the consulate of country A, is it possible to ask the UK consulate for such a document without lying that I lost my UK passport?

Comment: @David We don't have a blanket prohibition on hypothetical problems, and I think this is a valid if mildly odd question.

Answer (score 3):

**No, you cannot**.  Per https://www.gov.uk/emergency-travel-document:

> You can apply for an emergency travel document if all the following
>   apply:
>
> - you’re a British national
> - you’re outside the UK
> - **your passport has been**
>     **lost, stolen, damaged, is full, has recently expired or is with HM
>     Passport Office or a foreign embassy**
> - you do not have time to renew or
>     replace your passport before you travel
> - you can provide proof of your
>     travel plans, for example booking confirmations (or detailed written
>     travel plans if you cannot book ahead)

Note the bolded criterion: merely leaving it at home is not sufficient.

More broadly, if you're on such bad terms with country A that you're unable/unwilling to get replacement documents from them, you're probably better off not using their passport for travel.

Comment: For the last paragraph, country A could simply have a horribly dysfunctional consular service that just fails to be able to issue emergency documents in country Z. But if so, all the more reason to travel with the UK passport as a back-up -- or leave it with someone you trust at home who can courier it to you in case of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply for an emergency travel document if you’re abroad, need to travel and cannot get a passport in time, and if all the following apply:

- you’re a British national
- you’re outside the UK
- your passport has been lost, stolen, damaged, is full, has recently expired or is with HM Passport Office or a foreign embassy
- you do not have time to renew or replace your passport before you travel
- you can provide proof of your travel plans, for example booking confirmations (or detailed written travel plans if you cannot book ahead)

Source: https://www.gov.uk/emergency-travel-document

You have to apply online so I can’t ascertain whether you have to provide the reason why you need an ETD. But on the assumption that you do, given that forgetting or leaving your passport at home are not listed under the eligibility criteria, I’d say the answer to your question is ‘no’.

Lying that you lost your passport is pointless anyway, since you are required to cancel a lost or stolen passport https://www.gov.uk/report-a-lost-or-stolen-passport